MSBuild не применяются параметры окружения
Пытаюсь настроить процесс сборки в зависимости от переменной окружения
ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT из профиля сборки, но условие применения переменной не выполняется.
профиль сборки:

.csproj файл:
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Web">
    <PropertyGroup>
        <!--...-->
        
        <UseSpaProxy Condition="'$(ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT)' == 'Debug'">true</UseSpaProxy>
        <SpaRoot Condition="'$(UseSpaProxy)' == 'true'">..\web.client</SpaRoot>

    </PropertyGroup>
<!--...-->

</Project>

Переменная UseSpaProxy не принимает значение true. Создается впечатление, что переменные окружения из профиля не пробрасываются на этапе сборки проекта.
Можно ли как-то это исправить?

Вы путаете профиль сборки и профиль запуска. Приглядитесь внимательнее - там прямо так и написано, "профиль запуска".

Для сборки используйте конфигурацию (которая по умолчанию Debug/Release, но вообще-то может быть любой)
